# funktion that takes the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, date, variables, import

I´m new to R and I need some help to complete this tasks.

I´ve downloaded a csv file and imported it to R. Now I have to assign its content to a variable (i.e. a dataframe).

The other tasks are:

Write a function that takes the dataframe, district and year and lists the corresponding age group of the
mother and number of born children.

```
birthStats <- function(dataset, year, district) {
???
}
```

```html
DISTRICT_NAME;AGE_GRP_MOTH;SUM_LIVEBIRTH;YEAR
Innsbruck;0_18;16;2010
Innsbruck;19_24;140;2010
Innsbruck;25_29;267;2010
Innsbruck;30_34;355;2010
Innsbruck;35_39;227;2010
Innsbruck;40_00;47;2010
Arzl im Pitztal;0_18;3;2010
Arzl im Pitztal;19_24;1;2010
Arzl im Pitztal;25_29;8;2010
Arzl im Pitztal;30_34;9;2010
Arzl im Pitztal;35_39;3;2010
Arzl im Pitztal;40_00;0;2010
Haiming;0_18;0;2010
Haiming;19_24;1;2010
Haiming;25_29;14;2010
Haiming;30_34;17;2010
Haiming;35_39;8;2010
Haiming;40_00;4;2010
Imst;0_18;3;2010
Imst;19_24;15;2010
Imst;25_29;32;2010
Imst;30_34;22;2010
Imst;35_39;14;2010
Imst;40_00;4;2010
Imsterberg;0_18;0;2010
Imsterberg;19_24;1;2010
Imsterberg;25_29;1;2010
Imsterberg;30_34;4;2010
Imsterberg;35_39;0;2010
Imsterberg;40_00;0;2010
Jerzens;0_18;0;2010
Jerzens;19_24;1;2010
Jerzens;25_29;3;2010
Jerzens;30_34;7;2010
Jerzens;35_39;4;2010
Jerzens;40_00;0;2010
Karres;0_18;0;2010
Karres;19_24;1;2010
Karres;25_29;4;2010
Karres;30_34;2;2010
Karres;35_39;2;2010
Karres;40_00;0;2010
Karrösten;0_18;0;2010
Karrösten;19_24;0;2010
Karrösten;25_29;1;2010
Karrösten;30_34;3;2010
Karrösten;35_39;0;2010
Karrösten;40_00;0;2010
Längenfeld;0_18;1;2010
Längenfeld;19_24;5;2010
Längenfeld;25_29;19;2010
Längenfeld;30_34;16;201
```

Write a function that takes the dataframe, a year, and a vector of districts and then lists the corresponding number of children that were born during that year in each district (independent of the mother’s age group).

```
birthStats2 <- function(dataset, year, district) {
???
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: For the first question check out any function that imports tables like the function `import()` in the package `rio`. To get colums R needs to know what the separator will be. In your case it'll be the `;`. In most import functions that's specified via the argument `sep=";"`, but you'd have to look that up in the respective documentation/help. My guess is that `rio::import()` automatically detects the `;` as the separators and thus you'd only need `rio::import(file="path-to-your-file")`

Comment: Please consider reading this easy guide: https://www.statmethods.net/input/importingdata.html

Comment: Is this an academic assignment or a real world problem?

Answer (score 0):

So when you import a CSV into r it is by default a data frame. Considering you're new to r if the above answer proves to be too complicated it would likely be much easier to open the CSV file first in excel then arrange the columns how you want then import the excel file to r studio and you will have already accomplished your goals.